# getElementById returns empty from WP Variable

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget

So I have this widget that I coded base on wordpress standard. I declared a sort of variables to be use both backend and frontend purposes.

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    global $post;

    $sid = $instance['id'];

    $name = $instance['name'];

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'content_manager','post_id' => $sid);

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    echo $args['after_widget'];

}

public function form( $instance ) {

    global $post;

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'content_manager'); ....



    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );

    $sid = ! empty( $instance['id'] ) ? $instance['id'] : esc_html__( 'New ID', 'text_domain' );

    $name = ! empty( $instance['name'] ) ? $instance['name'] : esc_html__( 'Empty Content', 'text_domain' );
```

I am using the variables to get the values in javascript

```
   <script>

        function defineValue(sel)
        {
            var title = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            var id = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById("<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>").value = title;
            document.getElementById("<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'id' ) ); ?>").value = id;
            document.getElementById("<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'name' ) ); ?>").value = title;
        }

    </script>
```

When I load the widget, the inputs and other options displays the names and IDs but in Javascript returns empty unless If I save it first.

I tried to test it

```
 <?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'id' ) ); ?>
```

and this is the result

```
widget-content-loader-__i__-id
```

Why is that happen?

Notes:

First Inputs and other elements have ids and other attributes from that variables when I check in the DOM

```
<input class="widefat" name="widget-content-loader[21][title]" id="widget-content-loader-21-title" value="New title" type="text">
```

From this this script:

```
    <input
        class="widefat"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>"
        type="text"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cant get value unless it is loaded into DOM,
Make sure that the elements are loaded before calling definevalue()

Comment: okay, I added a notes, please have a look. Even if without javascript, I might be able to retrieve the data using <?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?> since it works on elements such inputs etc.. but it doesn't workout